# Blackberry web service slow

Tags: blackberry

I developed an application in blackberry consuming .asmx web service, response from the web service is slow when internet connection is slow. Do you think using WCF web service instead of .asmx web service can make the difference in communication? Can i make the data transfer fast?

Comment: "_response from the web service is slow when internet connection is slow_" - have you not answered your own question?

Answer (score 0):

If it's simply when the "internet connection is slow" then there isn't anything you can do about that other than reducing the footprint of the data being transferred. Depending on the type of data you could look at gzipping the content between the client and server.

Obviously you'll need to do your own benchmarking to ensure you're not causing more delays due to the additional CPU processing.

Comment: Due to slow connection, sometime connection is broken. And application does not get any response.

Comment: Internet broken problem is not frequent, most of the time data is loaded from the web service. but sometime not due to broken internet and lost of some data packets.